# Extracting Intersect Values in R

Tags: r, leaflet, geospatial

I am wondering if there was a specific way that would allow me to extract the sa3_code_2016 from the QLD sf object and add each corresponding value to the test dataframe.

Solved, needed to assign Points with the same CRS ad QLD and do a `st_join()`

Example data:

```
library(absmapsdata)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)


QLD <- sa32016 %>%
  filter(state_name_2016 == "Queensland") %>% 
  dplyr::select(sa3_code_2016,geometry)

Points <- data.frame(Longitude = c(148.275355, 148.872268, 150.490145),
                  Latitude = c(-23.683148, -21.228157,-22.705135),
                  names = c("First", "Second", "Last"))

Points <- st_as_sf(Points, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude")) %>% 
  st_set_crs(st_crs(QLD))
  
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data=QLD, 
              color = "#b3acc2",
              fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
  addMarkers(data=Points)


library(sf)
Test <- st_join(Points, QLD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error stems form filtering sa32016 but instead of using the filtered data you again use the unfiltered version in your selection process. this leads to your error. by assigning the full data to QLD and then going through the pipe, your process works just fine.

```
library(absmapsdata)
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)

QLD <- sa32016 # note this step
QLD <- QLD %>%
  filter(state_name_2016 == "Queensland") %>% 
  select(sa3_code_2016,geometry)

name <- c("First", "Second", "Last")
lat <- c(-23.683148, -21.228157,-22.705135)
long <- c(148.275355, 148.872268, 150.490145 )
test <- cbind(name,lat,long)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data=QLD, 
              color = "#b3acc2",
              fillOpacity = 0.5) %>%
  addMarkers(data=test,
             lng = long, 
             lat = lat)
```

Comment: That is strange, when I first wrote the example the filter worked just fine and I was able to see the markers and shapefile in the leaflet map but ran it just now and it gave me an error but your suggestion fixed it, thanks for that! 
What I am trying to achieve is to extract the "sa3_code_2016" from the shapefile where the marker lands and add the value in a new column to the test data frame.

Comment: i assume that in a first run you overwrote sa32016 instead of creating QLD and only then, for better readabilty, changed the name. that is how i usually mix stuff up :)
anyway always happy to help!